# Object expression for abstract class without abstract members

Tags: f#

Given an interface without members

```
type IFoo = interface end
```

it's possible to create an instance using an object expression

```
let foo = { new IFoo }
```

However, it doesn't seem possible to do the same with an abstract class having no abstract members.

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Foo() = class end

let foo = { new Foo() }
```

gives the error: *Invalid object expression. Objects without overrides or interfaces should use the expression form 'new Type(args)' without braces.* Well, we know that won't work either.

Here's a hacky workaround

```
let foo = { new Foo() with member __.ToString() = base.ToString() }
```

Is there a better way to create an object expression for an abstract type without abstract members?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any practical difference between a marker interface and a member-less abstract base class?

Comment: @pblasucci: Yes. An abstract class may provide functionality used by derived classes.

Comment: I don't know if there is a simpler syntax for doing that. However, if you want to create a new inherited class without overriding any members, then the class probably shouldn't be abstract - and you could just create instances of it directly, no?

Comment: @Daniel: ah, I see your point. I assume, based on the compiler error, simply adding some non-overridable member doesn't solve the issue?

Comment: @Tomas: Arguably, yes. It's abstract for purposes of symmetry. Also I don't want it publicly instantiable. Obviously, I could mark the constructor `internal`, but running across this oddity piqued my curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a better way.

I also don't know why you'd want to do this (abstract class with no members), but I'll just assume you have your reasons and leave it at that :)